# How to add iOS keyboard extension to react native?

Tags: ios, keyboard, react-native, ios-extensions

Starting with the default React Native project, I followed the guidelines for creating a Keyboard extension and the default Apple code works. But when I add `#import <RCTRootView.h>` to my file and the following is the only code in the extension ViewController file:

```
- (void)loadView {
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"ReactAGKeyboard"
                                           initialProperties:nil
                                               launchOptions:nil];
self.view = rootView;
}
```

The build will fail with error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from: objc-class-ref in KeyboardViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added `Other Linker Flags -ObjC` to the Extension Target Build Settings from this similar question [Using React Native within an iOS share extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990925/using-react-native-within-an-ios-share-extension)

My code is here: 
https://github.com/jeremyhicks/react-native-keyboard-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't linking your extension to react-native. You need to add the .a files which are presently in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` of your container app target (ReactAGKeyboard) to your extension target (AGKeyboard).